# Injecting Spring Boot properties into Kotlin Singleton / object

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, singleton

I have a Spring Boot 2 project, and I'm using Kotlin. What I want to achieve, is to have a Kotlin singleton (i.e. an **object**) and inject Spring properties.

Normally, I'd do this using constructor injection, which is the preferred way. However, for objects, constructors are not allowed. Another option is to use `lateinit var` combined with `@Value("\${my.property.name}")`, though then I'd have to initialize the field or explicitly set the type.

I could not find an example or similar situation for this, so I'm curious what the required approach is for this use case.

Answer (score 3):

Technically you can do this:

```
object MyObject {

    lateinit var foo: String
}

@Configuration
class BeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun myObject(): MyObject {
        return MyObject.also {
            it.foo = "foo"
        }
    }
}
```

but I wouldn't recommend this approach as it seems like a code smell. It is better to have simple `class`es as Spring guarantees that methods annotated with `@Bean` will only be called once (if they don't have a prototype scope).

Since `object`s don't need to be created you can manage its own lifecycle if you want, you don't need to put all your things in Spring.